# In Mongodb, how can i get posts by tags stored in user mode

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

post schema:

```
const BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    
    title: {
        type: String
      },
      content: {
        type: String
      },
      author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Tags
      },
      content_type: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Tags
      },
      valid_until: {
        type: Date,
      },
      timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
likes: { type: [String], default: [] },

},
```

);
user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

const UserProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
userid: {
type: String
},
firstname: {
type: String,
default: ''
},
tags: [{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'Tag'
}]
})
tag schema:

```
const TagSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String
},
type: {
    type: Object,
},
color: {
    type: String
},
timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
```

});
this code is in post controller it will aggregate posts

```
const blogs = await Blog.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "tags",
                    localField: "author",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "blog_tags"
                }
            }])
```

What can i do to make it only get posts that are in user tags

Comment: you can add a $match criteria to filter out undesirable records.  Another (probably more efficient) approach is to start by aggregating tags first then lookup blogs related to desirable tags.

Comment: Or you could embed your data and query on the nested data for even better performance.